# inaccurate data returned to swift button while scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview

I hope I am giving enough information by just showing the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" segment.  The entire program is too long.  Each row in my tableView represents a player and each player  has four buttons associated with him/her.  Based on an action of the player, I will press one of the buttons to record that action and keep a tally for each of the button presses in the titleLabel of that button.  I have created an array for each button to keep track of the number of button presses in each of the buttons, "plyZeroes", "plrOnes", "plrTwoes", and "plrThrees".  I use these arrays (plrZeroesArray, plyrOnesArray, etc) to save the correct value and then reload the button titleLabel with this correct value just before it it is redisplayed (in the event it has scrolled off the screen and then reappear).  At least that's what I think I am doing.  But it may be my lack of understanding of how cellForRowAtIndexPath works.

In the code segment below I have set breakpoints and have placed "print" statements at various places and I am confident that the array has assigned the correct information to each one of the "plrxxx" buttons just before the "return cell" statement.  However, when I run the application and if I scroll the device (iPad) enough, the count (text of the label) shown on the device is different than the value in the array (different than the value that was assigned to the button's textLabel).  If I scroll again to show the cell, the values become correct.  Basically when some cells disappear and reappear, the contain incorrect values about 30%- 50% of the time. Any ideas?

ps: there is another object "plrAvg" that is a label and I do the same saving of the data before it is returned, and it works fine all the time.

```
var plrNumbers: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
var players: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

var plrAverageArray = [String](count: 99, repeatedValue: "0")

var plrZeroesArray = [String](count: 99, repeatedValue: "0")
var plrOnesArray = [String](count: 99, repeatedValue: "0")
var plrTwosArray = [String](count: 99, repeatedValue: "0")
var plrThreesArray = [String](count: 99, repeatedValue: "0")

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell


    // Poputate the players' info, average, and last action//
    cell.hiddenLabel.text = ("\(indexPath.row)")

    cell.plrNumbers.text = (plrNumbers[indexPath.row] as! String)
    cell.plrNames.text = (players[indexPath.row] as! String)



    cell.plrZeroes.addTarget(self, action: "handleButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.plrOnes.addTarget(self, action: "handleButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.plrTwos.addTarget(self, action: "handleButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.plrThrees.addTarget(self, action: "handleButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.btnUndoLastPlrAction.addTarget(self, action: "handleButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)


    //restore the player's average in case it was lost because it scrolled off the screen
    cell.plrAvg.text = (plrAverageArray[indexPath.row])

    //restore the button text in case it was lost because it scrolled off the screen
    cell.plrZeroes.titleLabel?.text = (plrZeroesArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.plrOnes.titleLabel?.text = (plrOnesArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.plrTwos.titleLabel?.text = (plrTwosArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.plrThrees.titleLabel?.text = (plrThreesArray[indexPath.row])

print("Buttons \(indexPath.row)] = ", plrZeroesArray[indexPath.row] + plrOnesArray[indexPath.row] + plrTwosArray[indexPath.row] + plrThreesArray[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Once a button is pressed on a cell you actually have to reload that row using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths.

Comment: Thank you. I am nenes to swift and this is my first application like this so I don't know where to to use reloadRowsAtIndexPaths. I have tried to find examples of how to use but nothing seem to be obvious to me. Where do I do this reload? Is it in a separate function?